# Android - String Array to ListView

Tags: java, android, listview, android-listview, arrays

I am new to Android. Please help me. I have two String Arrays as below:

```
String[] Array1 = {"ele1", "ele2", "ele3", "ele4", "ele5", "ele6"};
String[] Array2 = {"obj1", "obj2", "obj3", "obj4", "obj5", "obj6"};
```

I have a listview in my layout as below:

```
<ListView 
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:id="@+id/lytlistView"
 android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
 android:layout_marginLeft="6dp"
 android:layout_marginRight="6dp"
 android:layout_below="@+id/lytListView">
</ListView>
```

Now i want to add two string array's values for listview as shown in the following:

```
-------------------------
listHeader1
listContent1
-------------------------
listHeader2
listContent2
-------------------------
listHeader3
listContent3
-------------------------
```

So, `listHeader[1,2,3,..]` contains `Array1[]` elements and `listContent[1,2,3,....]` contains `Array2[]` elements

How can i achieve that? Please help me.

Comment: you need to use hashmap for maping here..

Comment: use custom listview http://techdroid.kbeanie.com/2009/07/custom-listview-for-android.html

Comment: try reading [this blog post](http://bartinger.at/listview-with-sectionsseparators/) about sectioned listviews

Comment: do u have any cursor??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just wrap up the two arrays to a HashMap object,then simply use a SimpleAdapter.

Answer (score 0):

Declare String Array as per below.

Change This:

```
String[] Array1 = [ele1, ele2, ele3, ele4, ele5, ele6];
```

To

```
String[] Array1 = {"ele1", "ele2", "ele3", "ele4", "ele5", "ele6"};
```

You can do this using custom listview,

Check [HERE](http://www.technotalkative.com/android-listview-2-custom-listview/).

Comment: @user2326860 pleae refer link.

Answer (score 0):

To use a `ListView` you need to have an adapter.
One way would be to convert your two arrays into a single array {"ele1", "obj1" ...} and use an `ArrayAdapter`. The other way would be to write your own adapter.

If you are unfamiliar with `ListView` and using it with adapters, I recommend the following guide:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout.html#AdapterViews

Answer (score 0):

For this purpose you have to use BaseAdapter as an adapter to listView. Inflate a custom View that has two text view in your base Adapter class. then set that adapter to your listView.

```
      public class YourAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

Context mContext;
ArrayList<ClubDetailContent> mArrayList;

public ClubListAdapter(Context mContext,
        ArrayList<ClubDetailContent> mArrayList) {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    this.mContext = mContext;
    this.mArrayList = mArrayList;
}

public int getCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    return mArrayList.size();
}

public Object getItem(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return position;
}

public long getItemId(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return position;
}

public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View view = convertView;
    view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.listlayout, parent, false);
    //Add your text view here
            //set text to that textView according to your string

    return view;
  }


 }
```

then set adapter in main activity.